# How to secure EC2 server with just MySQL on it?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I have two servers. Let's call them EC2 A and EC2 B.

```
EC2 A = main server with PHP code
EC2 B = server with ONLY MySQL database. Right now, EC2 A is connecting to EC2 B.
```

What kind of security groups can I use to secure my EC2 A server for just the website access and EC2 B for just MySQL access from the EC2 A server?

Here is the security group I have for both EC2 servers:

```
HTTP 80
Custom TCP Rule 8080
SSH 22
SMTP 25
Custom TCP Rule 20-21
Custom TCP Rule 1024-1048
IMAP 143
MYSQL/Aurora 3306
HTTPS 443
```

Here is how I am connecting to the database in PHP PDO.

```
define ("DB_HOST", "ec2-**-***-*-***.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com");
define ("DB_USER", "dbuser");
define ("DB_PASS",'dbpassword');
define ("DB_NAME","dbname");
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=".DB_NAME.";host=".DB_HOST;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    return $dbh;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is there anything I can do to EC2 A **or** or EC2 B to make them more secure? is there anything I need to change to make it more secure or faster?

Comment: Side note: If your EC2 has only MySQL in it, why don't you use Amazon Aurora / RDS? It's a waste of resources.

Comment: Make sure your MySQL is not publicly accessible, and that only the MySQL port is open to the other EC2 instance.

Comment: For the best answer, edit your question and explain what ports you actually need open on each instance and what service is running on those ports. You have a number of ports open with no explanation why. Also consider moving EC2 B to a private subnet.

Comment: @JohnHanley What are the pros and cons of using a private subnet vs doing what Raptor said in his answer?

Comment: Private subnets cannot be accessed from the Public Internet. Create a new question for better details. The answer is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure the connection, you can specify the source (which is the EC2 A) in your security group's MySQL rule, i.e. only your EC2 A can connect to EC2 B via port 3306.

Comment: Okay thanks. I heard using MySQL on EC2 is more scalable, cheaper, and customizable. i could be wrong tho. Also another thing is that I have phpMyAdmin installed on EC2 B. How can I have access that?

Comment: Also, should I use a private subnet? What would be the pros and cons of that?

Comment: @TimmyBalk that's wrong. EC2 costs you storage, computing power as well as bandwidth (don't forget the time you configure the server). You can install the phpMyAdmin in EC2 A instead, where Apache web server is available. Then change the `config.inc.php` of phpMyAdmin to connect to EC2 B (or Amazon RDS).

Comment: And for private subnet, you still have to configure security group (for the best practice). Always limit the connection access to minimal.